# MoveIt: troubles with joint values

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just started with ROS and MoveIt! and I'd like to use it for planning trajectories on a Sawyer robot (ROS version: kinetic). I have followed the [tutorial on SDK intera webpage](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/intera/MoveIt_Tutorial) then I went through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pr2_tutorials/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html) linked at the end of that page.

After the commands `roslaunch sayer_moveit_config sawyer_movit.launch`and `roslaunch sayer_moveit_config group_movit.launch`, I ran  `python tutorial.py`, the script containing the code in the linked Python tutorial, with the only difference that I defined `group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("right_arm")` instead of left_arm (because Sawyer robot has only right arm).

Well, in Rviz I can see the planned trajectory. The problem arose while attempting to execute the plan: in the output I can read

1. a vector of zeros for 'positions', like in [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/jKV9QuHeFXU) (but I don't have to rename the joint_states topic, because for Sawyer the topic is already '/robot/joint_states')
2. "Joint values for monitored state are requested but the full state is not known", whilst `$ rostopic echo /robot/joint_states` shows a stream of positions..

Googling this error, I have found [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/move__group_8cpp_source.html)

```
if (!current_state_monitor_->waitForCurrentState(opt_.group_name_, wait_seconds))

ROS_WARN_NAMED("move_group_interface", "Joint values for monitored state are requested but the full state is not "known");
```

Do you have some some suggestion? What's wrong? I only have [these files](https://github.com/RethinkRobotics/sawyer_moveit) and the Python tutorial. Many thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281277/moveit:-troubles-with-joint-values/) by [BoBiBù](https://answers.ros.org/users/33484/bobib%C3%B9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing you should check is  whether your joint_states message contain all of the available joints

---

Originally posted by [weitang](https://answers.ros.org/users/33263/weitang/) with karma: 31 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0